# Android: specific file from list

Tags: java, android, file, listview, path

I want to read files in my Android app. In my activity I load files into a list and I show the path of the selected file. However, I require the `File` object for the next step, this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    private ListView mainListView;  
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;  

    String filepath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);  
        final ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();  

        final File storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        final File file = new File(storage, "/Folder/");

        if(file.exists() && file.isDirectory()){
            for (String s : file.list()){
                sb.append(s + " ");

                List.addAll(Arrays.asList(s));
            }
        }

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, R.id.rowTextView,List); 
        mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);  

        mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
                String filepath = new File("/Folder/"+ List.get(arg2)).getAbsolutePath();
            }
        });
    }
```

How can I solve this problem? The next method has as input (File file)

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I wrote File file2=new File (filepath); and in next method I have pdf reader with Adobe Reader on my phone but it doesn't open my file. There is the error: check the location